# PDO multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As of PHP version 5.3 `PDO_MYSQL` driver has been repleaced in favour of `PDO_MYSQLND`. It introduced support for multiple queries.

Though, I can't figure out how to get both result sets if more than one `SELECT` query has been passed. Both queries have been executed, it can't be that the second one was just dumped.

```
$db->query("SELECT 1; SELECT 2;")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Returns:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO support for multiple queries (PDO_MYSQL, PDO_MYSQLND)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd)

Comment: @FrancisAvila That is also my question and not a duplicate. I found the answer. Will post in a second.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It turns out that you need to use `PDOStatement::nextRowset`.

```
$stmt   = $db->query("SELECT 1; SELECT 2;");
$stmt->nextRowset();
var_dump( $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) );
```

This will return result for the second query.

It is a bit odd implementation. It would certainly be easier if multi-query statement would just return both results sets under one array. However, the advantage is that this implementation allows to fetch every query using different [FETCH styles](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).