# Sql error: General error: 25

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, pdo

```
$up = $this->db->prepare ("
        UPDATE ".self::DbUser." SET UserLogin=:UserLogin WHERE UserId=:UserId; 
        UPDATE ".self::DbUProfile." SET ProfileName=:ProfileName, ProfilePhone=:ProfilePhone WHERE ProfileUserId =:UserId");

$up->bindValue (':UserLogin', $UserLogin);
$up->bindValue (':ProfileName', $ProfileName);
$up->bindValue (':ProfilePhone', $ProfilePhone);
$up->bindValue (':UserId', $UserId);

if ( !$up->execute() )...
```

**As a result:  General error: 25 bind or column index out of range**

What is a problem? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot execute several queries at once.

Comment: @u_mulder I thought so, too, but I've found some info saying you can, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Comment: @Barmar interesting. Then the problem should be in duplicate `userId` placeholder.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) says (found through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34969455/50552)):

> The keys from input_parameters must match the ones declared in the SQL. Before PHP 5.2.0 this was silently ignored.

Try splitting the query in two, and for each `execute` specify only parameters that are used?