# Get total number of results using Sphinx MySQL

Tags: mysql, sphinx

How can I get the total number of results using mysql and sphinx?

First I tried with a PDO statement, which does return a number but it is not accurate.

```
$array = $pdo_sphinx->prepare("select * from `my_index` where MATCH ('@name ($search)') limit $start, $limit");
$array->execute(); 

$query = $pdo_sphinx->prepare("select COUNT(*) from `my_index` where MATCH ('@name ($search)')");
$query->execute();      
$total = $query->fetchColumn();
```

Then I read you can get `total_found` from `SHOW META` if you run it after the query

```
$array = $sphinx->Query("select * from `my_index` where MATCH ('@name ($search)') limit $start, $limit; SHOW META");

$total = $array['total_found'];
```

$total is returning 0, when it should be 9. How do I get the correct `total_found` from the query above? Is there a way to do this with the PDO statement?  I need the correct result for paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note when you add the 'SHOW META' it makes it a multi-query. There are two separate queries, each with their own resultset.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php
- [PDO multiple queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271595/pdo-multiple-queries)

(yes, using COUNT(*) may be inaccurate, because grouping can be somewhat approximate)